# Counting up/down numbers animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

I have an `UIPageViewController` with a number in the center of each `VC` in it.

I want that when I swipe from view to view, the number will begin at 0 and count up until it gets to the correct number (or if the number is negative - count down) like in this gif:

https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/345970/screenshots/2126044/shot.gif

How can I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/dataxpress/UICountingLabel
Try this

Comment: @khuong291 I've tried a `while` statement to add to the label 1 every time but it didn't work

Comment: @matiboo Thank you! That's what I was searching

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NSTimer to achieve this.

Here is example project I created for you.

Create layout like this:

[image]

Then in your `ViewController` do like so:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var countingLabel: UILabel!
    var number = 0
    var destinationNumber = 30
    var timer: NSTimer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func startButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "countUp", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func countUp() {
        if number < destinationNumber {
            number += 1
            countingLabel.text = "\(number)"
        } else {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

It will work.

Comment: You need to invalidate that NSTimer once you're done with it

Comment: Why? If I don't invalidate it, what happen in this case?

Comment: It will carry on being invoked by the run loop, which is pointless & wasteful. Also if you call `startButtonTapped` multiple times, you'll be added multiple timers to the run loop, which will also be wasteful and could result in an undesired outcome.

Comment: Ok. Updated. Thanks @originaluser2.

Comment: Thank you! It will work, I am using [UICountingLabel](https://github.com/dataxpress/UICountingLabel) for this but your answer will work as well, thanks once again!

Comment: It's easy, so you don't need to use that library.

Answer (score 1):

Do not overcomplicate with timers and invalidations, etc.

```
extension UILabel {    
    func countAnimation(upto: Double) {
        let from: Double = text?.replace(string: ",", replacement: ".").components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: "-0123456789.").inverted).first.flatMap { Double($0) } ?? 0.0
        let steps: Int = 20
        let duration = 0.350
        let delay = duration / Double(steps)
        let diff = upto - from
        for i in 0...steps {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay * Double(i)) {
                self.text = "\(from + diff * (Double(i) / Double(delay)))"
            }
        }
    }
}
```